# Rails can't modify frozen string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my controller I have:

```
def index
    @title = 'asdsadas'
    @kategoris = Tag.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")
    respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.json { render :json => @kategoris.map(&:attributes).map{|d| d.map{|d| d.map{|d| d.force_encoding("UTF-8") } } } }
    end
end
```

I get this error in view:

```
RuntimeError in Admin::TagsController#index

can't modify frozen string
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can't `force_encoding` on a frozen string since that would modify it. What you can do is work with a copy:

```
d.map{ |d| d.dup.force_encoding("UTF-8") }
```